# IIS web.config redirect www to non-www and http to https

Tags: iis, web-config

I'm getting a "example.com is currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500" from my browser when I use this code:

```html
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopprocessing="true">
<match url="(.*)"/>
<conditions logicalgrouping="MatchAny">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]"/>
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" appendquerystring="true" redirecttype="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

I'm trying to redirect both http://example.com and http://www.example.com to my ssl https://example.com.  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

If we just want to redirect the Http to https, it is enough to add the `{HTTPS}` server variable to match the `Non-HTTP` protocol.

```
   <rule name="Force SSL (https)" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.